# problems with modules while importing custom functions

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've created a Notebook with some custom functions to shorten my coding, mainly while plotting, but I have a problem with a custom function, while importing the ".py" file into another notebook.

Let's say I've created the "plots_custom_functions.py" file. Inside it I have such a function:

```
def get_label(TITLE, X, Y):
    ''' 
    this function appends the labels to a plot. Arguments in the following order:
    Title, x label, y label
    '''
    plt.title(TITLE)
    plt.xlabel(X)
    plt.ylabel(Y)
    plt.show
```

Now, I create another notebook and type:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plots_custom_functions
```

then I want to create one plot like that:

```
sns.histplot(data=my_data, x='my_x')

get_label('MY_TITLE', 'MY_X)', 'MY_Y' )
```

but I get an error like that:

```
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

Now, It seems like it can't load `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` somewhere.
I've tried to import it in the `plots_custom_functions` in different "positions" like at the beginning of the file and like inside the `get_label()` function I've created, but I still get the same error.

Where can the error be?

**[EDIT: SOLVED]**

I do not know why, but it works importing just one function at a time.

So, in my "plots_custom_functions.py" file I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_label(TITLE, X, Y):
        ''' 
        this function appends the labels to a plot. Arguments in the following order:
        Title, x label, y label
        '''
        plt.title(TITLE)
        plt.xlabel(X)
        plt.ylabel(Y)
        plt.show
```

Then, when invoking my custom functions in another Notebook I have to type:

```
from plots_custom_functions import get_label
```

And it works. It's not handy, but it works.

So, to make it handy we can type this:

```
from plots_custom_functions import *
```

And this is one of the reasons why we have better not create "too many" custom functions in just one ".py" file.

Comment: You can try :  from matplotlib import  pyplot as plt.

Comment: unfortunately, nothing has changed even with your suggestion...

Comment: [SOLVED]: I do not know why, but to make it work I have to import one function at a time, which is not quite handy... so it has to be something like from plots_custom_functions import get_label